# Custom developed form feature not displayed in Site collection Features

Tags: installation, features

I'm new in sharepoint.
I work with Sharepoint 2010 and have this problem :
when I install a solution, Although the package contains a feature (to update the ContentTypes).
The feature is not listed in the site collection features

If something can tell me from what it caused
I'll be grateful

Comment: It might be a hidden feature. Use the powershell cmdlt get-spfeature -Site http.//yoursitecollection | sort-object displayname

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify whether your feature is **Site** level or **Web** level. If you want your feature should visible to Site Collection then it should be configured **Site** level while developing.

For surety please check following thing:

- Go to **Site Settings**
- Under **Site Actions** click on **Manage site features**
- Check whether you locate your feature here

If you find your feature here, then you have developed **Web** level feature. So go to your solution, change it to **Site** level and deploy the solution again.